# What is the best way to allocate on heap: small pieces or big piece

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory

For example I have a code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    Object obj = new Object();
    /* Manipulation */
}
```

What is the best way to do this:

- Keep this version and allocate little pieces
- Or at start allocate `sizeof(Object) * 1000` and then use

I need this objects outside of loop.

I am thinking about problems, when heap cannot find chunk big enough as size I requested.

Comment: Are you planning to use `obj` outside the `for`?

Comment: It is worth to allocate them at once only if you delete them at once too, otherwise you are getting into trouble.

Comment: it depends on situation and the given scenario is too simplistic.

Comment: Allocation is costly (relatively speaking). While you don't want to waste memory (i.e. allocate `10000 int` when you anticipate using `800`), the most efficient memory management approach is to allocate your anticipated need at once, rather than in **"rabbit pellet"** fashion. There is nothing wrong with allocating `100` or `200` if you expect between `80-200`. If you allocate `100` and need more, `realloc` as needed. One, or two allocation calls beats the heck out of 100+ to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: "need more, `realloc`" - not sure if it's what you intend, but when readers on S.O. see backtick-generated "code" formatting for a word like realloc, it implies the specific function by that name and not the general concept of reallocation; the C library `realloc` function may needs to move the existing elements, that's potentially a lot of copying and doesn't work safely with C++ objects with non-trivial copyable objects or non-trivial destructors. Better to use `std::vector`, presize it if you can, then let it grow if necessary....

Comment: Sorry, originally the question was flagged as `C, C++`, `realloc` is `C`, so disregard and use the equivalent for `C++`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: oh I see... good call on `realloc` for C then.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

One larger allocation will save a little time during allocation and deallocation, assuming you want the lifetimes of the objects to be the same.  There could be reasons not to, but in general I'd recommend using `std::vector<Object> objects(1000);` before the loop, then modifying `objects[i]` inside the loop, or even looping...

```
for (Object& object : objects)
    ...
```

...if you don't need `i` for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, your code will not be efficient at all, no matter how you allocate. You're dynamically allocating thousands of bytes and never deallocating them; it doesn't matter if you do it in the loop or outside. On each iteration, you will take up more unused bytes in the heap.

Now, if you use stack allocation, then your object will be destructed implicitly after each loop iteration, and you don't need to worry about deallocating it manually.

But here's the thing—you don't need to allocate `sizeof(Object) * 1000` bytes, because either way the scope of your object is the loop. If you don't plan on accessing the object outside of the loop (and I don't imagine you would, since you're making thousands of them and the only one you'd retain access to is the last one), then you only need room for one object.

The C++ compiler actually does this automatically. When your function gets called, it will allocate `sizeof(Object)` bytes for the local variable `obj`, and on each iteration, you're just overwriting those same bytes.

So in short, the only thing you need to worry about is deallocating after each iteration, which can be achieved more simply by allocating on the stack as opposed to the heap.

There is slight overhead if you are to use dynamic allocation along with a `delete` at the end of each iteration. You will have `sizeof(Object)` bytes in the heap and also 4 bytes on the stack for the pointer to the heap, which is `obj`. 4 bytes is certainly negligible in most cases, but worth noting.

Of course, allocating those thousands of bytes for the `Object`s is much more memory-intensive than overwriting the same few bytes, especially if you only intend for the lifetime to be a single iteration.